Finit loop doesn't finishes or show segfault
I used GNU BC ( basic calculator ) for exponentiation 999,999 to 999,999 and it answered in 10 minutes but when I want to find 999,999 root of a big file ( 1.1 GB) it shows segfault after 5 hours and GDB core shows mpz_clear(y) is the problem and when I remove it , It takes 20 hours and nothing happens and loop doesn't finish ; Here's the code :
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fr, *fw;
    char filename[200];
    int size = 0;
    unsigned long int rt = 2;
    unsigned char ch[1] = {112};

    printf("Enter filename :\n");
    scanf("%s", &filename);
    fr = fopen(filename, "rb+");

    if (fr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening of file %s\n", filename);
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(fr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fr);
    fseek(fr, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char* buf = NULL;
    buf = malloc((size_t)size);

    fread(buf, size, 1, fr);
    if (ferror(fr)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during reading from file %s\n", filename);
        perror("");
        fclose(fr);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fr);
    fr = NULL;

    mpz_t x;
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_t y;
    mpz_init(y);

    mpz_import(x, size, 1, (size_t)1u, 0, 0, buf);

    do {
        mpz_root(y, x, rt);
        if ((mpz_cmp_ui(y, 999999)) < 0)
            break;
        else
            mpz_clear(y);
        rt++;
    } while (rt <= 99999);

    int rootnum = 0;

    while (rt != 0) {
        int num;
        num = rt / 10;
        ++rootnum;
    }

    memset(buf, 0u, size);

    mpz_export(buf, NULL, 1, (size_t)1u, 0, 0, y);

    printf("Enter copied filename :\n");
    scanf("%s", &filename);

    fw = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fw == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening of file %s\n", filename);
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(buf, mpz_sizeinbase(y, 10), 1, fw);
    if (ferror(fw)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", filename);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(fw);

    fw = fopen(filename, "ab+");
    fwrite(ch, 1, 1, fw);

    fclose(fw);

    fw = fopen(filename, "ab+");
    fwrite(&rt, rootnum, 1, fw);

    fclose(fw);

    free(buf);
    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_clear(y);

    return 0;
}

Can any one tell me why the loop doesn't finish and how to fix it ?
Thanks
I will be grateful
Edit : The code has been changed but segfault still exist and when I use GDB for debugging and open core file and enter the where command GDB shows mpz_clear(y) and if I remove it ( of course with else option ) the loop never ends ; The new code :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{

FILE * fr, * fw;
char filename[201];
unsigned long long int size = 0;
unsigned long int rt = 2;
unsigned char ch[1] = {112};

printf("Enter filename : ");
fgets(filename, 200, stdin);
filename[strlen (filename) - 1] = '\0';
fr = fopen(filename, "rb+");

if (fr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening of file %s\n", filename);
    perror("");
    return 1;
}

fseek(fr, 0L, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fr);
fseek(fr, 0L, SEEK_SET);

if (size == -1)
{

fprintf(stderr, "Size doesn't match\n'");
perror("");
return 1;

}

if ( size > SIZE_MAX)
{

fprintf(stderr, "The size of file is greater than acceptable\n");
perror("");
return 1;

}

unsigned char * buf = NULL;
buf = malloc((size_t)size);
if(buf == NULL)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "Buffer failure\n");
    perror("");
    return 1;

}

int r;
r = fread(buf, size, 1, fr);
printf("%d\n", r);
if (ferror(fr))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during reading from file %s\n", filename);
    perror("");
    fclose(fr);
    return 1;
}
fclose(fr);
fr = NULL;

mpz_t x;
mpz_init(x);
mpz_t y;
mpz_init(y);

mpz_import(x, size, 1, (size_t)1u, 0, 0, buf);

do
{
    mpz_root (y, x, rt);
    if ((mpz_cmp_ui(y, 999999))<0)
    break;
    else
    {
    mpz_clear(y);
    mpz_init(y);
    rt++;
}while(rt<=99999);

int rootnum = 0;
unsigned long int num = rt;

do
{

    num = num/10;
    ++rootnum;

}while(num != 0);

memset (buf, 0u, size);

mpz_export(buf, NULL, 1, (size_t)1u, 0, 0, y);

printf("\nEnter copied filename : ");
fgets(filename, 200, stdin);
filename[strlen (filename) - 1] = '\0';

fw = fopen(filename, "wb");
if (fw == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening of file %s\n", filename);
    perror("");
    return 1;
}

fwrite(buf, mpz_sizeinbase(y, 10), 1, fw);
if (ferror(fw)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", filename);
    perror("");
    fclose(fw);
    return 1;
}

fclose(fw);

fw = fopen(filename, "ab+");
if(fw == NULL)
printf("File can't be written\n'");
if(ferror(fw))
{

    fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", filename);
    perror("");
    fclose(fw);
    return 1;
    
}
fwrite(ch, 1, 1, fw);

fclose(fw);

fw = fopen(filename, "ab+");
if(fw == NULL)
printf("File can't be written\n'");
if(ferror(fw))
{

fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", filename);
    perror("");
    fclose(fw);
    return 1;
    
}
int w;
w = fwrite(&rt, rootnum, 1, fw);
printf("%d\n", w);

fclose(fw);

free(buf);
mpz_clear(x);
mpz_clear(y);

return 0;

}


Please use {} even for single statement ifs, to make more obvious what you think your code is doing. Also, some indentation would help with that (though it does NOT actually influence behaviour, other than in e.g. Python). Probably becaue of your use of break it won't matter, even if you are wrong about how if works without {}, but it would make reading so much easier.

How is the compression tag relevant to this?

scanf("%s", &filename); should be scanf("%199s", filename);. %s expects a char* but you give it a char(*)[200]. Better use fgets

@Yunnosch For one statements there's no need of {} It's good but not necessary

@Barmar This program writes files as root numbers of data , Then You can exp to get the lossless file back

@TedLyngmo They edited my post , I wrote this is a scratch and I want to expand it but endless loop was my problem

Why mpz_clear(y); if you are going to reuse y in the next iteration without reinitializing it?

@HadiLovelorn Re: "They edited my post" - I edited your code to make it readable.

I know, and with your feedback to my comment you cleary demonstrate that your misleadingly indented use of else mpz_clear(y); rt++; (before the indentation cleanup by Ted) in combination with a recent break; is an expression of your mastery of that detail. With that background, Teds indentation edit was of course unneeded and redundant.

Many holes.
Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings
Endless loop
rt is never changed.  num assigned a value that is never used.
Unclear what OP's goal is here.
unsigned long int rt = 2;
...
while (rt != 0) {
    int num;
    num = rt / 10; // conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'int' may change value 
    ++rootnum;
}

Overflow
size = ftell(fr); may lose upper bits.  Better as long size = ftell(fr); and check that size is not -1 nor more than SIZE_MAX.
Buffer overflow and loss of space characters
scanf("%s", &filename);  does not read file names with spaces in the name - nor filenames 200 or longer.  Use fgets() and lop off a potential '\n'.
Failure to check allocation success
buf = malloc((size_t)size); should be followed by a buf == NULL check.
Failure to check read
fread(buf, size, 1, fr); should check the return value.  Same for fwrite(&rt, rootnum, 1, fw);
Failure to check for success
fw = fopen(filename, "ab+"); deserves a following test: fw == NULL?

Likely more issues.

Thank You ; Great points ..... I fixed some of them , But since my computer is weak and here's middle night ; I will report result tomorrow

I changed the loop as :
int rootnum = 0;
unsigned long int rootnum2 = rt;
unsigned long int num;
do
{
num = rootnum2/10;
++rootnum;
}while(num != 0);
But still get segfault ; num gets the value of nth root value of file divided by 10

@HadiLovelorn "I changed the loop ...  still get segfault" --> Let me know how things are after applying all the other fixes, especially Enable all compiler warnings.  Consider posting a small sample data file so we can have a [mcve].

Should I edit my original post or open a new topic ?

@HadiLovelorn If your original key problem is solved, complete this post and then add a new question.  Add links to/from that post to this question.  If the questioned issue here is not solved, append new code and details.

I fixed all the points You mentioned but char filename[201]; fgets(filename, 200, stdin); can't take address of file ; They edited my OP , I have a 1.1 GB video file in the same directory with name : example.mkv ; Whether I write name of file or the address of file , program gives error : Error during opening of file example.mkv
No such file or directory

@HadiLovelorn "can't take address of file" is unclear.  What code needs the address of a FILE?

I found the solution , Thanks

italic fgets italic function must took the address of file like scanf , But it didn't there's a solution I found in stackoverflow

Alright , I'm going to replace the old code with new one but segfalt didn't fix
